# How do I fix an invalid syntax error in google colab?

Tags: syntax, google-colaboratory

Whenever I try to run this command, an error appears and I amn't sure what I'm doing wrong, here is the image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdqmg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change the extension from Parse_script **.jpynb** to Parse_script **.ipynb**